# How to show that the following function isn't a polynomial over Q?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Enumerate the rationals as $b_1,b_2,\dots$ and define the (set) function:
$$f(x) = (x-b_1)^2 + (x-b_1)^2(x-b_2)^2 + \dots.$$
At any particular $x$, only finitely many terms are non zero so this is perfectly well defined as a (set) function but surely, it is not equal to any polynomial! (or is it?) How do I show that there is no polynomial $p(t) \in \mathbb Q[t]$ such that $p(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb Q$?

If $f(x)$ were defined as $(x-b_1) + (x-b_1)(x-b_2) + \dots$, then this question is not so hard. If $p(x)$ has degree $n$, then testing on $b_1,\dots,b_n$ would show that $p(x)$ is necessarily $(x-b_1) + (x-b_1)(x-b_2) + \dots + (x-b_1)\dots(x-b_n)$ but then $x=b_{n+1}$ derives a contradiction.

I don't know how to adapt this approach. Trying to guess the polynomial seems hard even if we think $p(x)$ is degree $1$.

I posted a follow up to this question here: [(Variation of an old question) Are these functions polynomials?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288290/variation-of-an-old-question-are-these-functions-polynomials).

Comment: It is even conceivable that the question of whether $f(x),\mathcal{O}$ (where $\mathcal{O}$ represents some ordering in the enumeration of the rationals,)  is expressible as a polynomial, depends on the choice taken for  $\mathcal{O}$.  So a good question is whether there is *any* $\mathcal{O}$ and $p(t)\in\Bbb Q[t]$ for which $p(x) = f(x)$ for all rational $x$.

Comment: It's easy to see that then $f_1=f/(x-b_1)^2$ would have to be a polynomial too, but of lower degree. Then again $f_2=(f_1-1)/(x-b_2)^2$ would also be a polynomial of lower degree yet... and so on.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Very nice, I believe this approach handles generalizations to replacing the 2 by 3,4... and even replacing Q by any countable (infinite) field, no?

Comment: There may be a flow in my scheme: I'm no longer sure that it's obvious that $b_1$ is a zero of $f/(x-b_1)$ and thus that $f/(x-b_1)^2$ is indeed a polynomial...

Comment: @YaakovBaruch, I guess it boils down to:  if $p = (x - b_1)q$ as polynomials, and $f = p$ as functions, then $f/(x - b_1) = q$ as functions, right?

Comment: @ChristianRemling, but (modulo my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288259/how-to-show-that-the-following-function-isnt-a-polynomial-over-q#comment713736_288259)) this doesn't seem to show that the *polynomial* $p/(x - b_1)$ has a root.  That is, we can divide $f$ by $x - b_1$ 'canonically' to obtain a function $g$ (EDIT: oops, sorry, not your $g$), and we can divide $p$ by $x - b_1$ canonically to obtain a polynomial $q$, but it isn't *a priori* clear to me that $g = q$ (in other words, that these two kinds of division preserve equality).

Comment: @LSpice How do you make sense of $f/(x-b_1)$ at $x = b_1$ in your comment?

Comment: I agree that $f/(x - b_1)$ is not always well defined for a function vanishing at $b_1$.  In this case, though, each term in the defining sum for $f$ is a polynomial divisible by $x - b_1$, and so there is a natural sum of polynomials that deserves to be called $f/(x - b_1)$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling; I agree with LSpice. The *series* $f/(x-b_1)$ has values that agree with those of the *polynomial* $p/(x-b_1)$ at $b_2, b_3...$, and the *series* is $0$ at $b_1$ but since this series is a wild thing it needs not be continuous and we don't know that its value at $b_1$ tells us anything about the value of the polynomial there. As an example $(x-b_2)(x-b_3)(x-b_4)\dots$ is zero at $b_2, b_3,...$ but does not necessarily converge at $b_1$. Hamsterrific attemps to deal with this problem in his answer, but I don't think his argument is quite correct or complete.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For each positive integer $n$ and any rational $x$, we have
$$f(x)\geq (x-b_1)^2(x-b_2)^2\dots(x-b_n)^2.$$
For large $x$, we then have $f(x)\gg x^{2n}$, which implies that if $f$ is a polynomial, it must have degree $≥2n$.

Comment: Just curious: Do you see a way to prove something similar if we replace $\mathbb Q$ by $\overline{ \mathbb F}_p$ ?

Answer (score 4):

You can adapt the same approach as follows:  Say $p_n(x)$ is an $n$-th degree polynomial matching $f(x)$ at all rational points, then in particular,
$$
p_n(b_1) = 0\\
p_n(b_2) = (b_2-b_1)^2 \\ \vdots\\
p_n(b_k) = \sum_{i\in\Bbb Z+, i<k}\prod_{j\in\Bbb Z+, j\leq i} (b_k-b_i)^2
$$
For a given fixed sequencing of the rationals as $b_1, b_2, \cdots$, and for any given $k$, the latter expression is just some fixed rational number.

So $p(n)$ is fixed by its values at $b_1 \ldots b_n$, and now consider $-f(b_{n+1}-p_n(b_{n+1}))$.  Since all the terms past the  $n+2$ term in $f(b_{n+1})$ are zero,  $$f(b_{n+1}) = p_n(b_{n+1}) + \prod_{i\leq n}(b_{n+1}-b_i)^2 > p_n(b_{n+1})$$ which contradicts the statement that $f$ matches $p_n$ at all rationals.

Comment: why do $n$ values determine a degree $n$ polynomial? Don't you need $n+1$ terms?

Comment: Do you really mean to consider $-f(b_{n+1} - p_n(b_{n+1}))$ and not $-f(b_{n+1}) - p_n(b_{n+1})$? Is the idea to use that $f$ is always positive? How do you show that the difference between f(b_{n+1}) and $p_n(b_{n+1})$ is that expression?

Answer (score 1):

> "If $f(x)$ were defined as $(x−b_1) + (x−b_1)(x−b_2) + …,$ then this question is not so hard."

Does taking the derivative of the given function get you to this simpler case?

> "At any particular $x$, only finitely many terms are non zero"

But at irrational values of $x$, none of the terms are zero. Now, you may respond "But I'm talking about it over $\mathbb Q.$" But unless you're going to claim that $f$ isn't continuous,  if you take a sequence of irrationals approaching a rational, the function evaluated at that rational must be the limit of the function evaluated at those irrational numbers. You could also construct a sequence of rationals approaching $b_1$ such that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $x$ in the sequence, $f(x) > \epsilon$. If $f(x)$ is continuous, $f(b_1)$ must be $> 0$, but clearly by the definition of $f$, $f(b_1) = 0$. I suppose you'll still have to argue that $f$ must be continuous, but that should follow from it being a polynomial, even with the restriction to $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: It is not clear that the function is continuous, much less continuously extendible to $\mathbb R$, or differentiable.  (Also, the termwise derivative doesn't match this easier function.)  Even if the function extended continuously, your argument only shows that the same formula doesn't naïvely define the extension.

Comment: It's a proof by contradiction. I'm certainly not claiming that it **is** continuous, merely that if it *were* defined by a polynomial over **Q**, then it would be continuous.