# (Variation of an old question) Are these functions polynomials?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

This is a followup to the question here: [How to show that the following function isn't a polynomial over Q?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288259/how-to-show-that-the-following-function-isnt-a-polynomial-over-q).

As before, let $b_1,b_2,\dots$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$. The question might be sensitive to the enumeration (but probably not).

**Question 1:** Suppose I define $$f_3(x) =  (x-b_1)^3 + (x-b_1)^3(x-b_2)^3 + \dots,$$

how do I show that this function is not a polynomial? I do not believe the answers to the old question extend to this case since they all seem to use the positivity of squares.

Can we show that $f(x)$ is not a polynomial?

There is a even more general version (and the one I was interested in from the beginning) that I was interested in, however I forgot to omit the trivial cases/there was some ambiguity in the second question, so I asked it again here:

[Is the following function a polynomial?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288346/is-the-following-function-a-polynomial)

Comment: Clearly you can ask an infinite family of these questions, and probably most people don't want to answer each new variant individually.  What is the motivation?  (E.g., if this question is answered negatively, would that settle your curiosity, or is there some deeper question that these questions are meant to approximate?)

Comment: The tone of my question was misleading, I think these functions are not polynomials and would like to show that. Question 2 is what I am really interested in. Also, YaakovBaruch himself retracted his comment. It is not clear why $(x-b_1)$ divides the polynomial twice...

Comment: (Sorry, I saw @YaakovBaruch's retraction and deleted my comment about it before you responded.)

Comment: I answered both of your questions now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f_3(x)$ is not a polynomial function, which can be seen as follows. Call $b_n$ a champion if it exceeds all the earlier terms $b_1,\dots,b_{n-1}$. Clearly, there are infinitely many champions, and they tend to infinity. Let $m$ be fixed, and consider the champions $b_n$ with $n>m$. We get, as $b_n$ tends to infinity,
$$ f_3(b_n)>\prod_{k=1}^m (b_n-b_k)^3 = (1+o(1))\ b_n^{3m}. $$
This shows that $f_3$ has degree at least $3m$. As $m$ is arbitrary, the claim follows.

Comment: Over $\mathbb Q$, that is enough, of course. I'm curious though if we can take care of the convergence issue on the whole $\mathbb R$ as well (choosing a reasonable enumeration, of course) and make it the identity map everywhere.

Comment: @fedja: I don't know. I thought $G(x,y)$ was defined on $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The unique solution to this recurrence is $a_0=b_1$, $a_1=1$, and $a_n=0$ for $n\geq 2$. So the expression for $g$ is actually a finite sum.

Comment: @JulianRosen: Thanks a lot! I added this in the "Added" section.

Comment: @fedja: Julian Rosen's comment takes care of convergence...

Comment: Erm...  If we allow zeroes, I can just put *all* $a_k=0$ and get the identically $0$ function, which is certainly a polynomial. This, of course, is formally OK, but it is pretty clear that it is not what was meant...

Comment: @fedja: Anyways, you can represent any function $g:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ by choosing the constants $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$ recursively in terms of $g(b_1),g(b_2),g(b_3),\dots$

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the first question. For the second question... Certainly, if we let most of the $a_k$ be $0$, we end up with a polynomial but is this the only way to end up with a polynomial? I realize that I did not word my original question well to avoid this ambiguity but I hope you won't mind me editing the question to clear this up.

Comment: @user404577: As I said in my previous comment, by choosing suitable (nonzero) constants $a_k$, you can obtain any function $g:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$, including every polynomial function. I don't know the answer to your new Question 2, but it is generally not recommended to change a question after you get an answer to it. It is better to open a new question.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. I was not aware of that convention.

Comment: For any $n$, the functions $1$, $(x-b_1)$, $\ldots$, $(x-b_1)\cdots(x-b_n)$ are a basis for the space of polynomials of degree at most $n$. So if we try to solve for constant coefficients $a_k$ so that $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, we get $a_k=0$ for $k> n$.

Comment: @JulianRosen: Yes, I thought of that. Anyways, the OP transferred his Question 2 to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288346/is-the-following-function-a-polynomial

Comment: @JulianRosen: See also my response at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288346/is-the-following-function-a-polynomial